# How maxQueueSize and queueSizeRejectionThreshold work in Hystrix?

Tags: spring, hystrix

I try to understand how to use the `maxQueueSize` inside Hystrix.

According to my interpretation, if a server is not able to serve a request, then the clients will store the thread in the *queue* until the queue is full and then it throws an exception. And this behavior is independent of the `execution.isolation.thread.timeoutInMilliseconds`.

To demonstrate it I wrote two simple applications. "A" is the *client* which calls "B". In "B" I have set a breakpoint and called it from the method "A" which is annotated with `@HystrixCommand`.

```
@HystrixCommand(
    fallbackMethod = "fallback",
    commandProperties = {
        @HystrixProperty(
            name = "execution.isolation.thread.timeoutInMilliseconds",
            value = "20000"
        )
    },
    threadPoolProperties = {
        @HystrixProperty(name = "coreSize", value = "1"),
        @HystrixProperty(name = "maxQueueSize", value = "2"),
        @HystrixProperty(name = "queueSizeRejectionThreshold", value = "2")
    }
)
```

I have sent 6 requests, but none of them were rejected although the *threshold* was set to 2. Of course, every thread stopp`ed after 20000 ms as it was defined.

How should work the `maxQueueSize and` queueSizeRejectionThreshold`?

Comment: Have you considered reading [the documentation](https://github.com/Netflix/Hystrix/wiki/configuration#queueSizeRejectionThreshold)?

Comment: Yes, I have but I didn't get it.

Answer (score 1):

In the [documentation](https://github.com/Netflix/Hystrix/wiki/configuration#maximumQueueSize) it says that the `maximumQueueSize`

> ... cannot be resized or changed without re-initializing the thread executor which is not supported.

This means that if you want a *fixed queue* size, then you only need to set `maximumQueueSize` on start-up. And if you want to change the size at run-time, then you can set [`queueSizeRejectionThreshold`](https://github.com/Netflix/Hystrix/wiki/configuration#queueSizeRejectionThreshold).

As for why nothing was blocked in your application, are you sure that the requests you sent take a long time to process? In other words are you filling up the queue? If a request returns a response rapidly the queue won't get filled.